# How I fetch the data in Laravel using one foreign key in one table at multiple times?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Here is the attached image to show what I'm asking for?

[image]

In the **CheckedIn** model, I want to get the data that belong to the foreign key called **checkInUserID**.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `models` and `migrations` as these will help us provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply I've solved my problem. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a relationship between the two tables in your Modal. This will let you directly access all the values that are in relation to that particular Modal.

To know how it works check out [Eloquent-Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

You can also check out this tutorial [Laracast-Foreign-Keys](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/30) (Highly recommended for understanding)

Comment: Thank you for giving me the idea for solution now its fixed. (Y)